# ajax is always returning error with error return [object Object]

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Cart</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="user/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
  .badge-notify{
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    top: -20px;
    right: 10px;
  }
  .my-cart-icon-affix {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="container">

  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Products
      <div style="float: right; cursor: pointer;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart my-cart-icon"><span class="badge badge-notify my-cart-badge"></span></span>
      </div>
    </h1>
  </div>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
      <img src="images/img_1.png" width="150px" height="150px">
      <br>
      product 1 - <strong>$10</strong>
      <br>
      <button class="btn btn-danger my-cart-btn" data-id="1" data-name="product 1" data-summary="summary 1" data-price="10" data-quantity="1" data-image="images/img_1.png">Add to Cart</button>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Details</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
      <img src="images/img_2.png" width="150px" height="150px">
      <br>
      product 2 - <strong>$20</strong>
      <br>
      <button class="btn btn-danger my-cart-btn" data-id="2" data-name="product 2" data-summary="summary 2" data-price="20" data-quantity="1" data-image="images/img_2.png">Add to Cart</button>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Details</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
      <img src="images/img_3.png" width="150px" height="150px">
      <br>
      product 3 - <strong>$30</strong>
      <br>
      <button class="btn btn-danger my-cart-btn" data-id="3" data-name="product 3" data-summary="summary 3" data-price="30" data-quantity="1" data-image="images/img_3.png">Add to Cart</button>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Details</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
      <img src="images/img_4.png" width="150px" height="150px">
      <br>
      product 4 - <strong>$40</strong>
      <br>
      <button class="btn btn-danger my-cart-btn" data-id="4" data-name="product 4" data-summary="summary 4" data-price="40" data-quantity="1" data-image="images/img_4.png">Add to Cart</button>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Details</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
      <img src="images/img_5.png" width="150px" height="150px">
      <br>
      product 5 - <strong>$50</strong>
      <br>
      <button class="btn btn-danger my-cart-btn" data-id="5" data-name="product 5" data-summary="summary 5" data-price="50" data-quantity="1" data-image="images/img_5.png">Add to Cart</button>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Details</a>
    </div>

  </div>


  <script src="user/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="user/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="user/js/jquery.mycart.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
  
     var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content")||"";
   var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content")||"";

    var goToCartIcon = function($addTocartBtn){
      var $cartIcon = $(".my-cart-icon");
      var $image = $('<img width="30px" height="30px" src="' + $addTocartBtn.data("image") + '"/>').css({"position": "fixed", "z-index": "999"});
      $addTocartBtn.prepend($image);
      var position = $cartIcon.position();
      $image.animate({
        top: position.top,
        left: position.left
      }, 500 , "linear", function() {
        $image.remove();
      });
    }

    $('.my-cart-btn').myCart({
      currencySymbol: '$',
      classCartIcon: 'my-cart-icon',
      classCartBadge: 'my-cart-badge',
      classProductQuantity: 'my-product-quantity',
      classProductRemove: 'my-product-remove',
      classCheckoutCart: 'my-cart-checkout',
      affixCartIcon: true,
      showCheckoutModal: true,
      numberOfDecimals: 2,
      cartItems: [],
      clickOnAddToCart: function($addTocart){
        goToCartIcon($addTocart);
      },
      checkoutCart: function(products, totalPrice, totalQuantity) {
        var data = [];
        $.each(products, function(){
        var cols = [];
          cols.push(this.name,this.price,this.quantity);
          data.push(cols);
        });
        var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(myJsonString);
        
        
        $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
        }
    });
            $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/DBA_TOOLS/tracker",
        data: {myJsonString:myJsonString},
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data){
            if(data.status == "SUCCESS"){
                alert("AJAX request successfully completed:"+JSON.stringify(data));
            }else{
                console.log('Error Msg'+JSON.stringify(data));
            }
            console.log('Error Msg'+data.message+''+JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log('error while submit'+error);
        },
        complete: function() {

        }
    });
    
    
    
      }
    });
  });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

i am trying a demo from  http://asraf-uddin-ahmed.github.io/jquery.mycart/demo.html , but when i am sending ajax post to my controller then ajax is getting failed with error [object Object], ajax is not able to send simple string infact , i am not sure what wrong i did with my ajax part, i doubt its due to xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token); not getting processed properly but no hind how to fix this

Comment: whats the status code of error obj?

Comment: Also please make a [mcve] For example add your scripts from a CDN. Also jQuery is running stable in version 3.6.0 and you do not tell us which bootstrap you use

Comment: `[object Object]` means your converting an object to a string - sometimes via alert or concatenating with other strings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.

issue was with setRequestHeader(header, token);

i was missing below in my jsp file

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```